# What's the minimum distance between holes in a concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, drill

I'm fixing a pull-ups bar to a concrete wall. I need to drill some 15/32'' holes, but I have the feeling that two holes in the metallic frame are too close to each other.
They are less than an inch apart, for that big of an hole. I'm wondering if that is not too little spacing for the holes in the wall: I am afraid the wall could crumble, especially while drilling. I'm working with a concrete wall and a hammer drill.
Any advice?

Comment: Is the wall solid concrete or concrete block? How about putting a board on the wall with widely spaced concrete anchors, then using lag screws to attach the pull-up bar to the wood? How about [edit]ing in a clear, focused picture of the mounting point, including a tape measure/ruler for reference, so we can see just how close the holes are. Based on "I have a feeling" that they're too close, either they are or aren't but we can only guess based on your feelings...

Comment: @FreeMan  using an intermediate board is exactly what I'd do in this situation.  Makes it much easier to mod the setup at some future time, for one thing.

Comment: I'd be a bit worried about two essentially half-inch holes being only one inch apart - sure hope at least that's inner edge-to-edge, not center-to center.  BTW,  typical hole spacings specs in technical drawings are center-to-center.   What does the manufacturer's documentation suggest you should be mounting to?